# ios appium test on windows

Tags: ios, appium-ios

I was looking for information about how to test IOS apps with Appium, and I saw that all documentations are using Mac for demonstration. I wondered if I test run local tests and use Appium's IOS-inspector on Widnwos. So far I have found one source stating that it is impossible unless I install Mac Os on visual desktop. So I wanted to make sure that I have to use a Mac Os system to test IOS applications on iPhone/iPad, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you have to use Mac OS to test iOS apps, it will be a lot easier than to try and install a virtual machine trust me, since Appium it's a pretty robust framework you will have a lot less problems if you run it on a Mac